# en calma (noun expression) vs calmo (adjective)

Tags: selección-de-palabras

I heard the following sentence in the Narcos TV series:

> Gacha siempre se ponía paranoico cuando las cosas estaban en calma.

Could I use the adjective "calmas" instead of "en calma" here? Is there any difference in meaning? Is one of them more usual when used as predicative, as in this sentence?

Comment: "En calma" is prepositional phrase functioning as an adverb here.  (It's not an adjective.)  Here's something similar: *Si pones las cosas **en el refri**, no se echarán a perder.* (If you put the purchases in the fridge, they won't go bad.) // I'm not familiar with "calmas" as an adjective.  Did you find that in a dictionary?

Comment: @aparente001 it is the feminine plural of https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=calmo

Comment: I see, thanks.  Okay.  If you want to use *calmo* as an adjective, then you'd have "Las cosas estaban calmas" (which I was able to find with Google Books) -- similar to "Las cosas estaban tranquilas" (which would be much more common).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adjective [calmo](https://dle.rae.es/calmo) is correct but seems to be uncommon in Spain and (according to aparente001's comment) in Mexico. The adverbial phrase *en calma* is much more common. When used purely as an adjective (i.e., when not separated from its noun by *ser* or *estar*), *calmado* or *tranquilo* are also more common than *calmo*:

> Era una situación *calmada/tranquila*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is "calmado" more usual than "calmo" for any noun? I'm aware that Google search is not a reference, but "un día calmo" returns more results than "un día calmado".

Comment: @AlanEvangelista that is because "un dia calmo" is also a valid sentence in Portuguese... many of the Google results are in Portuguese.

Comment: The translation of "un día calmo" to Portuguese is "*um* dia calmo". That is why I added the article to the search.

Comment: @alan true, I had searched without quotes (""), so I was getting also the Portuguese results. With quotes, I get 5900 vs 6040 results, a small difference. Maybe the version "calmo" is more common in literature, as many of the first results are in books. In everyday speech, I never hear "calmo".

Comment: AFAIK "tranquila", as "calmada", would be more usual than "calma" as a qualitative adjective in your example sentence. I think it'd be nice to mention it in your answer.

Comment: @alan I have updated the answer